# Smartedit loading the site indefinitely and there is no error in server console

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Smartedit loading the site indefinitely and there is no error in server console.Anyone faced the similar issue?

Comment: Can you add an image when you try to authenticate to smart edit and what exactly happens?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the samed problem a couple of times, usually it's related to some missing extensions inside the localextensions.xml file. It would help if you added the steps that you made to configure smartedit.